# Ruby On Rails image_tag( ) Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quick question for the RoR experts out there.

I'm having a problem with getting the image_tag( ) method to properly format my HTML **img** element.

I'm pretty certain the reason my image will not load is because of the "/images/" directory that is being added to the front of the URL. (SEE BELOW)

---

**I'm calling the image_tag( ) method like this ::**
[image]

---

**I'm consuming MY method like this ::**

[image]

---

**This is the HTML  tag that's getting generated ::**
[image]

---

Anyone know why this **/images/** directory is getting placed on the front of my URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing https:/secure.gravatar.com... to https://secure.gravatar.com...

Notice you have only one '/'

Comment: Yeah but I'm guessing that the missing '/' is corrected by the browser. Did you test it in your rails app with '//'?

Comment: Oh my goodness.  My sincere apologies dude!!!  You were 100% correct.  I forgot that I generate the first portion of that URL and it was MY fault that it wasn't working.  The missing "/" was the problem.

Thank you so much for correcting me!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your URL.

An example:
If in my controller I use the following:

```
@my_image_url = "https:/localhost/desktop/02.png"
```

When I look at the generated page I get:

```
<img src="/images/https:/localhost/desktop/02.png" alt="bob">
```

If in my controller I use the following:

```
@my_image_url = "https://localhost/desktop/02.png"
```

When I look at the generated page I get:

```
<img src="https://localhost/desktop/02.png" alt="bob">
```